# Does Tmux support any form of command substitution for setting the value of options?

Tags: shell, terminal, debian, tmux

Consider the following hardcoded value of `default-shell`:

```
set -g default-shell /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Does Tmux support any form of command substitution for settings options, e.g.:

```
set -g default-shell "$(which bash)"
```

?

I've considered both `if-shell`and `run-shell`, but neither suit the purpose of something like command substituion.

Comment: Are you asking if the above command works? Did you try it?

Comment: @jeremysprofile, yes, I did try it, and it doesn't work. E.g. try `display "$(whoami)"`. Do you know whether Tmux supports command substitution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set and use variable in tmux.conf depending on whether an environment variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838828/how-to-set-and-use-variable-in-tmux-conf-depending-on-whether-an-environment-var)

Comment: It does not. The question I marked this a duplicate of was answered by one of the maintainers of tmux - it's the best option you have for this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `run-shell`, for example:

```
run 'tmux set -g default-shell "$(which bash)"'
```

Or for `default-shell` you could possibly use `SHELL`. In `.tmux.conf` you can use `$SHELL`, or use a format like `set -gF default-shell "#{SHELL}"`.

Comment: I like your `run-shell` example, which sets the `default-shell` globally for all sessions - also new sessions started later? I have opted for removing `default-shell` from my config, since it defaults to `SHELL`, which is set to my login shell.

Comment: Your `run-shell` command doesn't seem to work when run from `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: I'm using Tmux 3.1b. Indeed, if I run `run 'tmux set -g default-shell "$(which bash)"'` from within a Tmux session (`<prefix>-:`), then `default-shell` is set correctly. However, if I put this command in `~/.tmux.conf` that option is not set. Any ideas? Could it be that the command is run in the background and first finish running after Tmux has started? I'm on macOS Catalina, btw.

Comment: `run` is not put in the background unless you use `-b`. Does it work if you change `default-shell` to `@test` and see if that is set instead?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not advanced enough in Tmux to know how I can make use `@test` :(

Comment: Change the command to `run "tmux set -g @test "$(which bash)"` then see if `@test` is set inside tmux with `tmux show -g @test`.